# how to fit an image into a showcase box

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have this code, but the image is always out of the showcase box, I tried using align,float,position but none of these seem to work. how can I fix it?

```css
div#main {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.showcase-box {
  width: 330px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 5px 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 20px 10px 20px;
  background-size: contain;
}

.showcase-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1 class="showcase-heading">Showcase</h1>
  <div class="showcase-box">
    <img src="Images/POTC1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

thank you!!

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how is your question related to java? Java and JavaScript are two completely separate and different programming languages.

Comment: Nothing is clear. Provide the complete code (so that the image is uploaded too). And describe your problem specifically. If necessary, draw a diagram.

Comment: Not reproducible. Could be an issue of browser support for css "object-fit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `overflow:hidden;` and the `background-size:cover;` property, so that the image isn't visible when it's out of it's container.

```css
main {
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.showcase-box {
    width: 330px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 5px 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 20px 10px 20px;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.showcase-box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1 class="showcase-heading">Showcase</h1>
            <div class="showcase-box">
                <img src="" />
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

now, it should work!

[image]

Comment: hi, I really appreciate you taking the time to help. I tried your suggestion, it's really helpful but does not solve the problem. thank you

Comment: sorry, that's bad, I really cant's see your image, because it's located in your computer, the other solution is to add the background picture in CSS instead, try with adding a background-image property in CSS. maybe it could help?

Comment: @someone now it should work, I have edited it, look how it looks on my PC.

Comment: @someone hello there, I'm glad that this helps, can you please vote up my answer and set it as answered, it would help me much. Thank you very much and I wish you nice and fast coding!

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer to see if **your existing code** produces the correct results here.

```css
div#main{
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.showcase-box{
    width: 330px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 5px 15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 20px 10px 20px;
    background-size: contain;
    border: 1px solid red; /* added border so to see if image overflows */
}

.showcase-box img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <h1 class="showcase-heading">Showcase</h1>
    <div class="showcase-box">
        
        <img src="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/backdrops/abstract/preview/pink_wires.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it appears it does. I put the red border in to see if the image overflowed. It did not.

So the issue could be a browser support issue for "object-fit" or other css property.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the display: block for the showcase img, Unless you treat a image to be a block level element it cannot be aligned easily. Just a suggestion but not sure.

```
div#main{
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.showcase-box{
    width: 330px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 5px 15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 20px 10px 20px;
    background-size: contain;
}

.showcase-box img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Now add all the alignments and look

Answer (score 0):

you must write such a code

```
    .showcase-box{
    width: 330px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 5px 15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 20px 10px 20px;
    background-size: contain;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
    overflow:hidden;
    
}

.showcase-box img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

display flex with align items and justify content center will center your image in the center of the box